# Blazor TelerikAutoComplete in each list item

Tags: blazor, telerik

Does anybody have an example on how to use the Blazor TelerikAutoComplete within each row of data that is shown in a Blazor component?

For example the blazor component could be a 'TestResultsComponent' which allows you to add X lines to a simple . Each line gives the option to enter a person name and a score. The person name needs to be searched in the database 'Person' table by using the TelerikAutoComplete component.

Is it possible to have the search logic live within the 'parent' 'TestResultsComponent' component instead of each line its object?

Thanks in advance.